# is there a simple way to check which version(s) of material-ui are installed on the specific web application?

Tags: material-ui

similar to the way we could check jQuery version from the console as in:

```
jQuery.fn.jquery
```

I tried to search stackoverflow, and in google, and in material-ui documentation, but didn't find any.

Comment: I don't think the API has a version getter, so I extracted the version manually from the `package.json` file in the `node_modules` directory: `JSON.parse(require("fs").readFileSync(require("path").join(__dirname, "node_modules", "@material-ui", "core", "package.json"))).version)`